# How do I reset my Laptop to factory settings

Tags: format, sony-vaio, reset, factory-defaults, system-reserved-partition

I have a sony vaio and I need to reset it to factory defaults - pretty much a format. However "F10" or "ALt + F10" on start up do not work. I suspect the factory partition has been lost somehow.

The computer came with Windows 8.1. 
Model Number: SVT131A11W

Comment: You have two options. The first is to use the Reset feature within Windows 8.1.  Your second otion is to download a Windows 8.1 ISO, format your HDD, and install Windows 8.1

Comment: Do you still have the OEM partition with the drivers and applications for all the devices? If not, you will need to get them individually from the Sony support site after a generic Windows re-install.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "Reset this PC" feature in Windows 8. Detailed instructions can be found here: https://www.howtogeek.com/132428/everything-you-need-to-know-about-refreshing-and-resetting-your-windows-8-pc/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked; I used the link that Arty2 provided but it was not 100% correct. This is what worked for me:

> To reset your PC
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then
>      tap Change PC settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the
>      upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click
>      Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)
> 2. Tap or click Update and recovery, and then tap or click Recovery.
> 3. Under Remove everything and reinstall Windows, tap or click Get
>      started.
> 4. Follow the instructions on the screen.
>
> Note You'll be asked to choose whether you want to erase data quickly
>   or thoroughly. If you choose to erase data quickly, some data might be
>   recoverable using special software. If you choose to erase data
>   thoroughly, this will take longer but it makes recovering data less
>   likely.

Found at:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/17085/windows-8-restore-refresh-reset-pc